# Formatting the Nested JSON response from retrofit API in MVVM Architecture - Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I m new to kotlin and MVVM, I have been working around this issue for a week now, couldn't get any idea even after searching for some code on the internet.

I'm trying to edit or modify the retrofit response (to observe a specific type; say "sf") according to my need and neglecting other data which is not needed. I'm using mutable livedata to fetch and update the JSON data from the retrofit response to the recylerview.

Here is the link for the JSON data: http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=HMM

3 Data classes based on JSON response:

```
data class sf(

    @SerializedName("sf")
    @Expose
    val sf : String? = null,

    @SerializedName("lfs")
    @Expose
    val lfs : List<lfs>? = null,
)
```

```
data class lfs(

    @SerializedName("lf")
    @Expose
    var lf : String? = null,

    @SerializedName("freq")
    @Expose
    var freq : Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("since")
    @Expose
    var since : Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("vars")
    @Expose
    var vars : List<vars>? = null,

) : Serializable
```

```
class vars (

    @SerializedName("lf")
    @Expose
    var lf : String? = null,

    @SerializedName("freq")
    @Expose
    var freq : Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("since")
    @Expose
    var since : Int?

): Serializable
```

Code in Activity:

```
listUsers = mutableListOf()

        adapter = WordAdapters(this, listUsers )
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        wordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,
            WordViewModelFactory(this)).get(WordsViewModel::class.java)
        wordViewModel!!.getData().observe(this, { t: ArrayList<sf>? ->
            listUsers.clear()
            t?.let { listUsers.addAll(it)
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


  })
```

ViewModel:

```
class WordsViewModel ( context: Context) : ViewModel() {

private var listData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<sf>>()

init {
    val wordRepository: WordsRepository by lazy {
            WordsRepository
        }
        //if (context.isInternetAvailable()) {
            listData = wordRepository.getMutableLiveData(context)
       // }
    }

    fun getData(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<sf>> {
        return listData
    } }
```

Repository:

```
    object WordsRepository {
    
        var call: Call<MutableList<sf>>? = null
        fun getMutableLiveData(context: Context) : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<sf>> {
    
            val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<sf>>()
    
            //context.showProgressBar()
            call = NetworkApiClient.apiService.getWordsMatching("HMM")
            call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<MutableList<sf>> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<MutableList<sf>>, t: Throwable) {
                    //hideProgressBar()
                    Log.e("error", t.localizedMessage.toString())
                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<MutableList<sf>>, response: 
                            Response<MutableList<sf>>)
                {
                    //hideProgressBar()
                    if (!response.isSuccessful){
                        Log.e("Code " , response.code().toString());
                        return
                    }
                    val raw: okhttp3.Response = response.raw()
                    val usersResponse : MutableList<sf>? = response.body()
                   /* if (usersResponse != null) {
                        for( movie in usersResponse[0].lfs!!){
                            Log.v("MainActivity", movie.vars.toString())
                        }
                    }*/
                    Log.e("Output : ", usersResponse.toString())
                    usersResponse?.let { mutableLiveData.value = it as ArrayList<sf> }
                }
    
            })
    
            return mutableLiveData
        }
    }
```

this is the base structure of JSON: here "sf" is a string, lfs is the array, according to this JSON response link provided I get 8 lfs arrays, but currently after parsing the recyclecount is 1 which is the same in the adapter itemcount method, so I get one row displayed in recylerview and rest are ignored.

JSON response:

```
[
{
"sf":"HMM",
"lfs":[
{
"lf":"heavy meromyosin",
"freq":267,
"since":1971,
"vars":[
{
"lf":"heavy meromyosin",
"freq":244,
"since":1971
},
{
"lf":"Heavy meromyosin",
"freq":12,
"since":1975
},
{
"lf":"H-meromyosin",
"freq":5,
"since":1975
},
{
"lf":"heavy-meromyosin",
"freq":4,
"since":1977
},
{
"lf":"heavy meromyosin",
"freq":1,
"since":1976
},
{
"lf":"H-Meromyosin",
"freq":1,
"since":1976
}
]
},
```

I want to ignore "sf" string after response and parse the ArrayList which is present under the "sf" which is "lfs", so based on "lfs" I need to display the data.

Mutable live data is not accepting any other type other than sf, since I placed the observer on it.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I'm observering the "sf" data model which is root object, but im trying to get the arraylist "lfs" under "sf", this is where type cast issue is happening which actually returning null data to recyclerview.

Comment: if im using the current data model , i get the data, but if change the data model, it throws error like "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT" - im using retrofit2

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

On the json you posted, there is only one parent item ( one sf ), but you are actually trying to pass the 8 lfs children. You have to perform such transformation somewhere, it could be on the network call directly, like this:

usersResponse?.let { mutableLiveData.value = it[0].lfs as ArrayList }

Take into account two things:

1. It could be better to check if "it" is not empty before going for the first item.
2. This only works if you will always have only one item on the parent array ( this sounds strange since if this is the case then the service should be returning an object, not a list, as the root of the json. If you will receive more than one object you will have to map the response into a single list of lfs. Something like (pseudo code since I'm from my phone):

   It.map( item -> item.lfs)

Comment: Yes this json response always has one parent, that's is for sure. 1st: i have tried null check on it object 2nd: casting will not be possible as i'm observing the sf only, if i try to observer "lfs" it just returns null.

Comment: usersResponse?.let { mutableLiveData.value = it[0].lfs as ArrayList }, this statement will not compile as im oberving the "sf", cannot able to cast

Comment: Sergio Pardo - thanks for the reply, i have tried the above suggestions, but it didn't help me out.